Properties inside then clause of a if-then clause is not supported when generating python classes from quicktype
I'm try to generate python classes from a JSON Schema and I'm using quicktype for that. But my schema contains if-then clauses and the in the then clause there's another property but the relevant class generated code doesn't contain the class in the then clause. How to solve this? Is quicktype supporting drafts before DRAFT-7 of JSON Schema?
My Schema
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "ExampleSchema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "type": {
            "enum": [
                "apple",
                "banana"
            ],
            "description": "The type of the fruit."
        }
    },
    "if": {
        "properties": {
            "type": {
                "const": "apple"
            }
        }
    },
    "then": {
        "properties": {
            "color": {
                "enum": [
                    "red",
                    "green"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

What I got
    from enum import Enum
    from dataclasses import dataclass
    from typing import Optional

    class TypeEnum(Enum):
    """The type of the fruit."""

        APPLE = "apple"
        BANANA = "banana"

    @dataclass
    class fruits:
    type: Optional[TypeEnum] = None
    """The type of the fruit."""

What I expected
    from enum import Enum
    from dataclasses import dataclass
    from typing import Optional

    class Color(Enum):
    GREEN = "green"
    RED = "red"

    class TypeEnum(Enum):
    """The type of the fruit."""

    APPLE = "apple"
    BANANA = "banana"

    @dataclass
    class fruits:
    color: Optional[Color] = None
    type: Optional[TypeEnum] = None
    """The type of the fruit."""


if, then is not available before draft-07 so I don't think you need to consider that. Secondly, I'm not a python developer, but I wonder if it doesn't recognize the property because it's not defined outside of the then clause. Try adding required to the then clause. Otherwise, you can try adding color: true to the main schema just to define it.
